# Is there a linux tool that will print Load Average and CPU percent idle every x seconds?

Tags: cpu-usage, terminal, load-average

I cannot seem to find a tool that prints LOAD AVERAGE and CPU PERCENT IDLE every X seconds in a terminal window.
I am looking for something along the lines of vmstat but with those two values that top shows.

Comment: What is the main problem you are trying to debug?

Comment: An mx server under attack. I block ranges of IPs and everything is fine for a while. So I am basically watching to see when it gets attacked without wanting to overburden it with loads of statistic pings I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dstat`:

```
dstat -tcl 10
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Would you happen to know why a LOAD AVERAGE of less than 1 is yellow and less than .50 is red? I was working under the impression that a low load average is good and a high load average is bad. There's no MAN entry for this program to explain.

Comment: The colors in `dstat` are meade to show variation in data, not to show if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

vmstat provides measures of load, but only over vmstat's measurement interval, not dampened over time. `procs` section has counts of `r`unnable and `b`locked (uninterruptible). Add the two for more or less an instantaneous (Linux) load average.

Over in the `cpu` column, `id`le is fairly straight forward.

---

Why not both? `uptime` to get the load average and the last reboot. `vmstat 5` to watch run queues, paging, and CPU busy. `top` to sort tasks by CPU or memory.

Healthy load average varies. Much greater load average than the number of CPUs may be a symptom of an overloaded system.

Comment: I couldn't see a relationship between the vmstat procs section and top's load average. I also didn't see any relationship between vmstat idle and top's idle numbers.